# I need to assign specific static IP in ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04, server, webserver, wired, ip-address

i have one ADSL Router and static IP for ISP's public ip..i need to set this public ip in ubuntu server and i can access out site world of this server.

Please guide me am new to ubuntu server

Comment: You have only one public ip? If yes probably is assigned on wan interface of router and you nedd to do port fw. If you have range of public ip's you nedd to set one of lan interface of router, then to setup server. Please give us more details.

Comment: A static ip received from ISP is for every computer you can't change this in ubuntu

Comment: I Have one static public IP..and how to assign with ubuntu server in static ip pls guide me on step by step

Comment: You mention "ADSL Router", but did you mean to say "ADSL modem"? If it is a router, then you must do as per the comment from 2707974. If it is a modem, then how you proceed depends on your ISPs requirements. For example, I have an ADSL modem and static IP addresses, but my ISP still requires me to get those static addresses via DHCP.

Answer (score 2):

Your ISP affects a public IP to your ADSL Router.

Your ADSL router affects a "private" or local IP to your ubuntu server.

You can say that you ubuntu server is "behind" your ADSL router.

If you have connected your ubuntu server to your ADSL Router, the ubuntu server should have a local IP.

To check the IP of your ubuntu server run this command on it :

```
ifconfig
```

In the result you should see something like this

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:50:99:8e:0c:54
      inet adr:192.168.1.23  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
      adr inet6: fe80::d250:99ff:fe8c:c79/64 Scope:Lien
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Packets reçus:2008950 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2299433 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000
      Octets reçus:1001461226 (1.0 GB) Octets transmis:492411283 (492.4 MB)
```

Where **inet adr** is your local IP. (Here 192.168.1.23)

Now if you want to access your server from the outside you have to enable port forwarding to the application you want to access.

For example if you want to run a web server on your ubuntu server you have to forward port 80 to your ubuntu server.

For example, let's say that :

- Your public IP is `85.191.215.47`
- Your private IP is `192.168.1.23`
- A visitor public IP is `97.176.24.123`

When someone want to visit your website which is setup on your ubuntu server, he will request : `http://85.191.215.47` but we all know that all navigators transform it into this `http://85.191.215.47:80` because 80 is the default port for web.

Your ADSL router receives a request from `97.176.24.123`, forwards request from its public interface to `192.168.1.23:80`, your ubuntu server, that's it, someone communicated with your ubuntu server from the outside !

To enable port forwarding you have to search how to do it for your ADSL model, search "port forwarding on router model XXX" and follow the procedure.

**This is the way to talk from the outside with your ubuntu server, by enabling port forwarding on specific applications.**

If you want your public IP to be accessible every time it depends wether or not you ISP provides static IP forever or renews it when you reboot your ADSL router, it may vary.

The best way to go is to configure a **DynDNS**.

1. Register on some site like http://www.noip.com, create a domain name (ex : myubuntuserver.ddns.org)
2. In your ADSL router find a DynDNS section and fill it up with your noip credentials, this way your ADSL router will warn noip when your ISP give you a new public IP.

Eventually you can access your ubuntu server web site with `http://myubuntuserver.ddns.org`